# How to handle negative values (transformation/constant)

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation

My question is regarding handling negative values prior to performing multiple linear regression.

I have a data set that includes approximately 1000 observations (individuals). I have 30 dependent variables (biomarkers) that I would like to analyse using linear regression against a number of independent variables. Values for the biomarkers were generated by a colleague at another institution, modelled on an approx. 10% subset of the sample that were analysed in Japan using a different technique. Due to uncertainty in the results from Japan when biomarker concentrations are low, some of the modelled values in my colleague's data are zero or negative. This only occurs for a few of the 30 biomarkers. Negative values are not physiologically feasible.

For a given biomarker, if there are no zero or negative values then log transformation prior to performing the multiple regression results in normally distributed residuals.

For the few biomarkers containing zero or negative values, I have not been able to transform so that regression residuals are normally distributed. Neither using inverse hyperbolic sine, negative log, or log(abs(x) + 1).

What would be the most appropriate way of addressing the negative and zero values in this situation?

Many thanks

Comment: With a generalized linear model and logarithmic link, the assumption is only that the mean response is positive rather than that all the values are, so some zeros and negatives in the response can be tolerated. That's often better than log transformation of the response for that reason alone, and in any case you have much more flexibility about error family. Even with what you're doing normally distributed errors is the least important assumption in regression.

Comment: Your colleague might do better to choose a model which does not predict impossible values then your problem goes away. But as @NickCox states normality of the residuals is low on the list of anxieties.

Comment: @NickCox, thank you for your response. I will do some reading on the generalized linear model.